# Check if each object in array of objects contains a value that is in another array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

If I have the following array of objects:

```
    const movies = [
        {
            movieTitle: "The House That Jack Built",
            movieGenre: "Thriller",
            movieDirector: "Lars Von Trier",
            movieStarring: "Matt Dillon, Uma Therman",
        },
        {
            movieTitle: "Mother!",
            movieGenre: "Thriller",
            movieDirector: "Darren Aronofsky",
            movieStarring: "Jennifer Lawrence",
        },
        {
            movieTitle: "Hot Fuzz",
            movieGenre: "Comedy",
            movieDirector: "Edgar Wright",
            movieStarring: "Simon Pegg",
        }
    ]
```

and the following array:

`const filters = ["Jennifer Lawrence", "Comedy"]`

How can I create a new array containing only the objects that have a value that's in the filters array (in this case the last 2)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const movies  = [{movieTitle:"The House That Jack Built",movieGenre:"Thriller",movieDirector:"Lars Von Trier",movieStarring:"Matt Dillon, Uma Therman"},{movieTitle:"Mother!",movieGenre:"Thriller",movieDirector:"Darren Aronofsky",movieStarring:"Jennifer Lawrence"},{movieTitle:"Hot Fuzz",movieGenre:"Comedy",movieDirector:"Edgar Wright",movieStarring:"Simon Pegg"}];
const filters = ["Jennifer Lawrence", "Comedy"];

const res = movies.filter(
  movie => Object.values(movie).some(v => filters.includes(v))
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Tried various combinations of these but couldn't get it right